# How do you SELECT multiple tables, but only LIMIT one table

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a question about SQL (SQLite). I have the following database:

- `table_parent` with columns `ID` and `name`
- `table_child` with columns `ID`, `name` and `table_parent_ID` (`table_parent_ID` points to a `table_parent` row)

I want to perform a `SELECT` query, to load parents and corresponding children. The result can be very large, so I want to LIMIT the result. To be more precise, I want the `LIMIT` the amount of `table_parent` records, but find all matching `table_child` records:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_parent 
LEFT JOIN table_child ON table_child.table_parent_ID = table_parent.ID 
WHERE table_parent.name LIKE ‘%searchtext%’ 
   OR table_child.name LIKE ‘%searchtext%’ 
LIMIT 100
```

The code above does not work as I want. If it finds contains a 100 related `table_child` rows for the first `table_parent` row, SQL will only return 1 `table_parent` (with its 100 children).

I also tried it with 2 separate `SELECT` statements:

```
SELECT DISTINCT table_parent.* 
FROM table_parent 
LEFT JOIN table_child ON table_child.table_parent_ID = table_parent.ID 
WHERE table_parent.name LIKE ‘%searchtext%’ 
   OR table_child.name LIKE ‘%searchtext%’ 
LIMIT 100
```

I can use the table_parent records it returns, to create a very long SQL statement, based on each table_parent.ID:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_child 
WHERE table_child = <ID1> 
   OR table_child = <ID2> 
   OR table_child = <ID3> 
   OR .... 
   OR table_child = <ID100000>
```

But the code above does not work if LIMIT is too high. The SQL string becomes too long and I get an error.

How would you select a limited number of records from a table, and an unlimited number of related records from another table, in an efficient way? Both tables have fields that need to be searched. Multiple SELECT statements is not a problem.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if LIMIT can be used in a subquery in sqlite syntax, but this is the idea

```
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT * 
          FROM table_parent
         WHERE table_parent.name LIKE ‘%searchtext%’
         LIMIT 100
       ) prnt
  LEFT 
  JOIN table_child 
    ON table_child.table_parent_ID = prnt.ID
 WHERE table_child.name LIKE ‘%searchtext%’
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll do something like: SELECT ... FROM ... LEFT JOIN ... ON ... LEFT JOIN ... ON INNER JOIN
(SELECT ... AS innerid FROM ... WHERE ... LIMIT 100) ON ... = innerid ORDER BY ...

Answer (score 1):

You could use `DENSE_RANK()` window function to get the rows of only 100 parent ids:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT *, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY p.ID) rnk 
  FROM table_parent p LEFT JOIN table_child c 
  ON c.table_parent_ID = p.ID 
  WHERE p.name LIKE '%searchtext%' OR c.name LIKE '%searchtext%'
)
WHERE rnk <= 100
```